# Ajax and Django, sending me to just a json string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I had a index page where the user could select a few things on a form (not backed by a model) and then hopefully send off those parameters to the next form.  I read that passing post data from one form to the next isn't ideal (So my design is probably not) though i just was trying to accomplish a quick proof of concept.

Since it wasn't ideal, I thought AJAX on the index form that could come back with the results of the selected params from that form would be the key.  I haven't done much Ajax especially in django and so I used this website here to get some bearings:

[How to submit form without refreshing page using Django, Ajax, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647715/how-to-submit-form-without-refreshing-page-using-django-ajax-jquery)

I got the code I thought implemented correctly... yet when I click submit on the form it it shows me a page with just a json string on it.

views.py:

```
def change_detection_index(request):

#this is a good attempt at an ajax call...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ChangeDetectForm(request.POST)
        message = 'something wrong!'

        if form.is_valid():
            points = form.cleaned_data.get('points')
            delta = form.cleaned_data.get('delta')
            #frefresh the list with this info... ajax way.
            message = str(points) + " " + str(delta)
            # do something with your results

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))

    else:
        form = ChangeDetectForm

    return render_to_response('swsite/changedetection/index.html', {'form':form },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

index.html template

```
{% extends "swsite/base2.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}
<script src= "{% static 'swsite/js/changedetection_index.js' %}" ></script>


{% block title %}NGA Research-SW: Projects{% endblock %}
{% block content %}


<section class="wrapper style4 container">

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="content">
        <section>
        <div class="message"></div>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="Submit Feedback" />
            </form>
        </div>


        </section>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

```
class ChangeDetectForm(forms.Form):
    delta = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    objectlist = ChangeDetectCSV.objects.all()
    #multiple select option here taken from the damn code
    points = ModelChoiceField(queryset=ChangeDetectCSV.objects.all(), empty_label = "Select points")
```

javascript:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e){
    $.post('/url/', $(this).serialize(), function(data){ ... 
       $('.message').html(data.message);
       alert(data.message);
       // of course you can do something more fancy with your respone
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Maybe I used this too verbatim.  But I am curious what causes the submit to display this:

[image]

It is almost like the js isn't getting called (I see no alert pop up) but I also see no console errors in the web developer console.

Comment: Your `<form>` element has no `#form` id attribute.

Comment: thanks, I discovered more issues but that was def one of them.  Got it all working :)