# how to prevent form submit when validation from server send failed in django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a login page, when user write username and password, I want to pass this information to server(post) and if I have error i want to just show error message and if I have not error so I want to submit it, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647715/how-to-submit-form-without-refreshing-page-using-django-ajax-jquery/11682152) case always prevent form submit.
In the below code always prevent submit and get error message from server and show it:
**login.js**

```
   $('#login-form').submit(function(e){

    var message;
    $.post('/login/', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        message = obj.message;
        alert(message);
});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**view.py**

```
// if username and password is faild
message="login information is failed"
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'message': message}))
//else with specific data
return render(request, 'front/member.html', data)
```

I want to do like this:

```
if(message) e.preventDefault();
// else submit
```

but first e.preventDefault(); execute and then message set from server
what can i do for this problem?

Comment: are you using Django's form ?

Comment: @JPG yes, and in `// if username and password is faild` I used form.valid

Comment: You can use [**`form.is_valid()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.is_valid) to check the validation and can show the errors by [**`form.errors`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors). Can't you?

Comment: @JPG In .js file?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to alter the js file, I'm unaware of that. But, it could be possible without altering js file

Comment: You can post data into form. The form will take care about the validation. If the validation broke, (username and password not matched) form will return an `HTTP 400` status code.

Comment: Can you add complete `view` ?

Answer (score 0):

> but first e.preventDefault(); execute and then message set from server what can i do for this problem?

This is because JavaScript is asynchronous: the function completes before you can get the response from the server because `$.post` request will run in the background.

---

You have two options to fix this:

1. Instead of catching `$('#login-form').submit`, you can catch `$('submit-button').click`.
2. Or you can serialize the form data and send it using another `$.post`.